# Vue method called when clicking on component element

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Strange behavior, I have function called sum.
This functions should be called once                             (after getting data from the server, and it's what happening) 
but then it's getting called every time I click on other elements in the component...it could be even select element or date selector...everything that have v-model defined (I think)

What I'm missing here?

Thanks!

```
<td><span>{{_sum('device')}}</span></td>
```

** important : this td element is not defined inside loop.

[image: Call stack is the same as when the data is returning from the server]

Comment: Why are you calling a function from the expression? Why don't you use `computed` properties?

Comment: @varit05 cause I'm getting error  "TypeError: _vm._sum is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it...the solution is to attach the main object 
(the one who responsible for the table data) to a watch property.
Now only when the table items getting an update the function will execute.